# Finding smilies with Pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to find emotions for example ":)", ":(", ":\", ":/" in a written text. 
I tried to quote the emotions because ( is a start for a group for regular expressions.
        String emotions = Pattern.quote(emotions);
but still I am not able to find the emotions.

Comment: contains.(":)"); doesn't work for you?

Comment: I am already using Pattern and I want to stick with it.

Comment: why? you're not actually looking for a pattern but exact matches

Comment: @AmendraShrestha What pattern, *exactly*, did you try, and how did it not work?

Comment: I have more than 10K words to search and my text is really really huge. So using contains might not be efficient. And why is the down vote?

Comment: @AmendraShrestha - And what makes you believe that `Pattern` and `Matcher` will be more efficient? :)

Comment: _using contains might not be efficient_ Have you tried?

Comment: @AmendraShrestha don't know about why the downvote. possibly because you still haven't shown a single line of code.
If we're talking about 10K words ... what do you expect from efficiency? you think that if you use a regex it only compares the first 250 words?

Comment: @AmendraShrestha This is *really easy* to do with regex. But you're not really asking an actual question, so I'm not sure with which part you need help. If you were do show your efforts and explain how they fail, then we could help you.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thank you guys for you time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern to match your emoticons:

```
/(:\))|(:\()|(:\\)|(:\/)/
```

Comment: Or just `/:[)(\\\/]/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String someText = "Some text with smilies! :D I really love it :)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\Q:)\\E|\\Q:D\\E|\\Q:(\\E|\\Q:wink:\\E)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(someText);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of unnecessary `\Q…\E`.